# Not able to read data from smart contracts

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-debugging, integers, state-variable

I am doing PoC on Ethereum using Azure Ethereum network and Web3. I was working from last 1 month and I have created one smart contract for student management and that was working like fab. But for some reason I have deleted my Azure Ethereum network and created a new one. I have followed all the steps which I did previously, but its showing error in formal verification section like

> Error: Type int256 not supported for state variable

The same smart contract code was working fine previously. Transactions are happening from Metamask but I cant read the data from functions so I am able to figure our where the exact issue is?

```
~pragma solidity ^0.4.9;
contract SimpleTest {
    int public count;

    function IncCounter()
    {
        count++;
    }

    function GetCounter() constant returns(int)
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

I have searched for this issue but didn't find anything valuable, can someone please help me understand the exact issue and how to resolve it quickly.

Comment: **Where** does it show the error? **What** do you do to trigger the error? **What** steps are you following?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a compiler error (I have no idea what is "formal verification section").

Most likely Solidity compiler has been upgraded to a newer version that comes with stricter checks.

However it is impossible to tell unless you include your contract source code and actual errors in the question. Please edit the question and use Markdown code formatting capabilities to add the necessary details.

Comment: i was edited post and added code which i was tried to use. today i am trying to run contract methods after 3/4 Days but still same issue is there

Comment: I have resolved this using web method contract.new(). i have deployed smart contract from node js using web3 provider.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract code works fine:
[image]

your variable `count` is public anyways. you can just try using the automatic getter `SimpleTestInstance.count()`
my guess the problem you had was with `uint` and `int`. Remember that `int` or `uint` stands for `uint256` and `int256`. So depending on the type signatures of your contracts, it may be wrong.

link to fiddle: https://ethfiddle.com/C6ARx6vyyo